# Loading isOn or isOff for a UISwitch using Swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiswitch

I am working on a project where I need to load a switch to either be .isOn or .isOff using Swift 4. I can do this in the main storyboard of the project by setting the switch to on or off, but I want the switch to be on or off based a boolean in my database for each user.

```
    //Create outlet for UISwitch
    @IBOutlet weak var switchBool1Outlet: UISwitch!

viewDidLoad() {
    //pulling data from Google Firebase to get true or false value    
    dataRef.reference().child("USERS/\(uid!)").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
                    {
                        //MARK - Local Variables
                        var bool1Value = dictionary["bool1"] as! Bool

                        //trying to set switches here, this is not working
                        if bool1Value == true && bool1Value != nil {
                          //following throws error: "Expression resolves to an unused l-value"
                          self.switchBool1Outlet.isOn
                        }
        })
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can get my UISwitch to load on/off based on the true/false value in my database?

Comment: You didn't specify what is `mealPlan`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch

Comment: @M.Wojcik Intended to change that bool1Value for the sake of this example. My app has to do with meal swipe sharing at my university. Appreciate the comment!

Comment: Thanks, @Adrian! The link is really helpful and has helped me answer a couple other question. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to change switch state, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch/1623686-seton)

```
self.switchBool1Outlet.setOn(true, 
  animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Fahadsk! This is exactly what I was looking for!